# PHP str_replace scraped content with wild card?

Tags: php, preg-replace, simple-html-dom

I'm looking for a solution to strip some HTML from a scraped HTML page. The page has some repetitive data I would like to delete so I tried with preg_replace() to delete the variable data.

Data I want to strip:

```
Producent:<td class="datatable__body__item" data-title="Producent">Example
Groep:<td class="datatable__body__item" data-title="Produkt groep">Example1
Type:<td class="datatable__body__item" data-title="Produkt type">Example2
.... 
...
```

Must be like this afterwards:

```
Producent:Example
Groep:Example1
Type:Example2
```

So a big piece is the same except the word within the data-title piece. How could I delete this piece of data?

I tried a few things like this one:

```
$pattern = '/<td class=\"datatable__body__item\"(.*?)>/';
$tech_specs = str_replace($pattern,"", $tech_specs);
```

But that didn't work. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well maybe my question wasn't that good written. I had a table which I needed to scrape from a website. I needed the info in the table, but had to cleanup some parts as mentioned. The solution I finally made was this one and it works. It still has a little work to do with manual replacements but that is because of the stupid " they use for inch. ;-)

Solution:

```
   \\ find the table in the sourcecode
   foreach($techdata->find('table') as $table){

    \\ filter out the rows
    foreach($table->find('tr') as $row){

    \\ take the innertext using simplehtmldom
    $tech_specs = $row->innertext;

    \\ strip some 'garbage'
    $tech_specs = str_replace("  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class=\"datatable__body__item\">","", $tech_specs);

    \\ find the first word of the string so I can use it    
    $spec1 = explode('</td>', $tech_specs)[0];

    \\ use the found string to strip down the rest of the table
    $tech_specs = str_replace("<td class=\"datatable__body__item\" data-title=\"" . $spec1 . "\">",":", $tech_specs);

    \\ manual correction because of the " used
    $tech_specs = str_replace("<td class=\"datatable__body__item\" data-title=\"tbv Montage benodigde 19\">",":", $tech_specs);

    \\ manual correction because of the " used
    $tech_specs = str_replace("<td class=\"datatable__body__item\" data-title=\"19\">",":", $tech_specs);

    \\ strip some 'garbage'
    $tech_specs = str_replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t","\n", $tech_specs);
    $tech_specs = str_replace("</td>","", $tech_specs);
    $tech_specs = str_replace("  ","", $tech_specs);

    \\ put the clean row in an array ready for usage
    $specs[] = $tech_specs;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a wildcard:

```
$newstr = preg_replace('/<td class="datatable__body__item" data-title=".*?">/', '', $str);
```

`.*?` means match anything but don't be greedy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string looked like this:

```
$string = 'Producent:<td class="datatable__body__item" data-title="Producent">Example';
```

You could get the beginning and the end of the string with this:

```
preg_match('/^(\w+:).*\>(\w+)/', $string, $matches);

echo implode([$matches[1], $matches[2]]);
```

Which, in this case, will throw **Producent:Example**. So, then you could add this output to another variable/array you intend to use.
OR, since you mentioned **replacing**:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^(\w+:).*\>(\w+)/', '$1$2', $string);
```

But then again, checking as it would probably come in a variable number of lines:

```
$string = 'Producent:<td class="datatable__body__item" data-title="Producent">Example
Groep:<td class="datatable__body__item" data-title="Produkt groep">Example1
Type:<td class="datatable__body__item" data-title="Produkt type">Example2';

$stringRows = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);

$pattern = '/^(\w+:).*\>(\w+)/';
$replacement = '$1$2';
foreach ($stringRows as &$stringRow) {
    $stringRow = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $stringRow);
}

$string = implode(PHP_EOL, $stringRows);
```

Which will then output the string like you expect.

Explaining my regex:
the first group catches the **first** word until the two dots `:`, then another group to catch the **last** word. I had previously specified anchors for both ends, but when breaking each line this wouldn't work as expected, so I kept only the beginning.

```
^(\w+:) => the word in the beginning of the string until two dots appear
.*\>    => everything else until smaller symbol appears (escaped by slash)
(\w+)   => the word after the smaller than symbol
```

Comment: I tested it at http://phptester.net/ and it worked like a charm. Got this as output: **Producent:ExampleGroep:Example1Type:Example2**, where did you test?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. It works when you only have 1 line string: $string = 'Producent:<td class="datatable__body__item" data-title="Producent">Example'; But when you have the string with more lines it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Maurice69, the first section of my answer is considering as if you would divide the content of a page in multiple lines to check one by one. The second one is considering the full content, in which case the output would be strictly only the string as I posted above.

Comment: 1) Your `echo $string;` just print the original `$string`, you didn't assign the result of `preg_replace`. 2) If you assign the result, you'll get `Producent:Example2`. QED: It doesn't work!

Comment: Betrayed by the code tester, unbelievable. Mea culpa anyway. Ok, will fix asap (thank you). Apparently any other php tester prints the error but this one. (LOVELY) might as well downvote the answer man, this one was well deserved.   (sorry)

Comment: Don't worry, I rarely downvote, I prefer explain what doesn't work before ;)

Comment: Quite honorable, and lesson learned. Never trust online testers fully.